# React Starter Kit - passing in style object instead of class name

Tags: css, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering, react-starter-kit

With [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)'s [Isomorphic CSS style loader for Webpack](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader) how'd I pass in the style object instead of the class name?

We can currently do this:

```
<div className={s.root}>...</div>
```

and I wonder if we can do something like this:

```
<FooBar style={s.root.toObject} />
```

I'm looking for a solution that also works when server-side rendered.

Comment: Maybe `<FooBar style={s} />`? FYI, `isomorphic-style-loader` just appends the two properties - `s._getCss`, `s._insertCss` to the styles object returned by `css-loader`. Maybe you can explain what actual problem you're trying to solve? Because passing the styles object via `style={..} prop` might not be the right way of approaching this problem..

Comment: Example: the dialog component here http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog has the following options `actionsContainerStyle` and `overlayStyle` which need style objects rather than class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you want to convert a piece of CSS into inline style object? E.g. `.comp { border: 1px solid red; }` would become `{ comp: { borderWidth: 1px, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: 'red' }`. For this task you may want to search for another NPM package (both `css-loader` and `isomorphic-style-loader` are intended to solve a different problem). Try [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium).

Comment: The .scss would have: `.comp { border: 1px solid red; }` Then I'd like `{ border: "1px solid red" }` with which I can pass around. Possible? Or will I need to go Redium?

Comment: Yep, Radium or a similar library that converts CSS string into a JS object.